# Output unique years from multiple duplicate years

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In the loop below, it outputs only the year data from datepicker in a repeater custom field. There can be multiple objects within the same year. I'd like to merge any group of duplicate years into one, so that I can set up the years filter later.

```
<?php
    if (have_rows('list_link_items')) :
        echo '<select>';
        while (have_rows('list_link_items')) : the_row();
            $date = get_sub_field('date', false, false);
            if ($date) :
                $date = new DateTime($date);
                $date = $date->format('Y');
            endif;
            echo '<option>', $date, '</option>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
?>
```

Currently, it outputs:

```
<select>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2009</option>
</select>
```

What I want (without duplicate years):

```
<select>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    ...
    <option>2009</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would store the years in an array, then remove the duplicates and output the options list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the most efficient way, but I'd do it like this. Also accounts for the fact that dates don't have to be in chronological order on input. Note that output order is still dependent on the order of the input, but since this isn't in the question, I haven't taken it into account.

```
<?php
    if (have_rows('list_link_items')) :
        echo '<select>';
        $dateList = []; // List to keep track of dates
        while (have_rows('list_link_items')) : the_row();
            $date = get_sub_field('date', false, false);
            if ($date) :
                $date = new DateTime($date);
                $date = $date->format('Y');
                if (!in_array($date, $dateList)) :  // If date isn't in list
                    echo '<option>', $date, '</option>';  // echo it
                    $dateList[] = $date;  // and save the date to the list
                endif;
            endif;
        endwhile;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
?>
```

**Side note for very minor performance improvements**

If you're 100% sure that the input list is always ordered, you can even replace the array for a string and only check against the previous date.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

Basically, just use an array to keep track of the dates that have already been used by adding a key with the value of the date.  Then check to see if that key exists before `echo`ing.  If the key exists, you know you've used it before, if not then go ahead and echo.

```
<?php
    if (have_rows('list_link_items')) :
        echo '<select>';

        // keep track of dates we've used
        $datesUsed = [];

        while (have_rows('list_link_items')) : the_row();
            $date = get_sub_field('date', false, false);
            if ($date) :
                $date = new DateTime($date);
                $date = $date->format('Y');
            endif;

            // only echo if the value hasn't been used yet
            if(is_null($dateUsed[$date])) echo '<option>', $date, '</option>';

            // add this date to the list so we don't use it next time
            $datesUsed[$date] = 1;

        endwhile;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
?>
```